# nginx 404 on root/homepage with Django + Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm migrating my website from one host to another. The migration has been mostly 99% successful except for the fact that whenever I navigate to the home page of the site, I get nginx's 404 page. Every other page, static & media file is rendered properly. I've wracked my brain trying to find a solution but I haven't found any, let alone someone having a similar issue (instead, others have a working home page but 404 on all others).

I have two different domains (one that my company owns, the other is owned by the city we're in). I've updated the DNS on the domain I own to ensure it's working with the new host and it is. When I navigate using the host (example.com) or the server's IP address, the website loads all pages correctly - *except* the homepage, which - again - returns nginx's 404. All other 404 errors display the 404 page I've set up via Django.

Whenever this issue crops up, the gunicorn error log adds a line stating that the service is 'Booting worker with pid: ...'

**nginx.conf** --> save for the paths and port, this conf is identical to the conf running on my current host

```
http {

    client_max_body_size 30M;       

    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=300s;
    open_file_cache_valid 360s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors off;

    upstream cgac_server {
    server unix:/root/cgac/cinema_backend/cinema_backend.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location /static/ {
           expires 365d;
           root /root/cgac/cinema_backend/static/;
        }

        location /media/ {
           expires 365d;
           root /root/cgac/cinema_backend/media/;
        }

        location / {

           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_redirect off;

           if (!-f $request_filename) {
             proxy_pass http://cgac_server;
             break;
           }
    }
}
```

**gunicorn.service** --> gunicorn is setup differently from the active server but the parameters in this file are identical, and it's working.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/cgac/cinema_backend
ExecStart=/root/cgac-venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile /root/logs/gunicorn-access.log --error-logfile /root/logs/gunicorn-error.log --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/cgac/cinema_backend/cinema_backend.sock cinema_backend.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Django URL patterns** --> also 100% identical to the working site

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^fobi/', include('fobi.urls.view')),
    url(r'^fobi/', include('fobi.urls.edit')),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

Comment: What is the `if (!-f $request_filename)` for?

Comment: @RichardSmith , my understanding (I didn't actually code this myself) is that it checks if a file exists and, if it does, it passes the request to the upstream server which is gunicorn. Per the [nginx common pitfalls resource](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#check-if-file-exists), that's not how it should be done. For what it's worth, if I move the proxy_pass line outside of the if-statement, the site still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had absolutely nothing to do with the nginx or gunicorn configuration. It turns out that an image in a carousel on the home page somehow got corrupted or something and it was driving Django crazy. I deleted the entry in the CMS which fixed the issue, then proceeded to reupload the file and it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

many option are there to fix it

1. put your upstream over http {}
2. reload your daemon
3. restart your gunicorn.service
4. your cinema_backend must be /run/cinema_backend.sock(what is normal)
5. try to use different config like site-availabe